# status_breakpoint error at Chrome newest ver. 121.~~

Tags: google-chrome, version

'status_breakpoint' error at Edge, Chrome(newest ver. since 2024/01/25~)
chrome- 121.0.6167.86
edge- 121.0.2277.83

it occurs on specific site.
and i'm the developer of the site.

i thought it was due to the time difference in the script, and confirmed thar it was also related to the 'hide()' function in the script.

Is there anything I can do about this?

The number of error occurences was reduced throufh the 'setTimeout()' function.